# Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’error in Monad instance definition

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, monad-transformers, applicative

I'm writing a haskell program to execute a bunch of statements to modify a data record. I would like to make modifications and tests to the state at each statement without user intervention. I had the idea to modify the [Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html) module to incorporate my specific type in a tuple `(,)`.

It worked well until I had the following error

```
• Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      (>>=) :: forall a b.
               StateT s m a -> (a -> StateT s m b) -> StateT s m b
    at TestMon.hs:38:7
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      (>>=) :: forall a b.
               StateT s m a -> (a -> StateT s m b) -> StateT s m b
    at TestMon.hs:38:7
  Expected type: m (b, s, LogS)
    Actual type: m (a, s, LogS)
```

and I don't understand why I get this error.
My code is like this :

```
module TestStateJLJ1  where

import Data.Functor.Identity
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

data LogS = LogOK { stepS:: Int ,logS::[String] }
          | LogErr {stepS:: Int , logS::[String] }
         deriving (Show)

initLogS = LogOK { stepS=1, logS=[]}

type State s = StateT s Identity

state :: (Monad m) => ((s,LogS) -> (a, s,LogS)) -> StateT s m a
state f  = StateT (return . f )

newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: (s,LogS) -> m (a,s,LogS) }

instance (Functor m) => Functor (StateT s m) where
    fmap f m = StateT $ \ (s,l) ->
        fmap (\ (a, s',l') -> (f a, s',l')) $ runStateT m (s,l)

instance (Functor m, Monad m) => Applicative (StateT s m) where
    pure a = StateT $ \ (s,l) -> return (a, s,l)

    StateT mf <*> StateT mx = StateT $ \ (s,l) -> do
        (f, s',l') <- mf (s,l)
        (x, s'',l'') <- mx (s',l')
        return (f x, s'',l'')

    m *> k = m >>= \_ -> k

instance (Monad m) => Monad (StateT s m) where
    return a = StateT $ \ (s,l) -> return (a, s,l)

    m >>= k  = StateT $ \ (s,l) -> do
        (a, s',l') <- runStateT m (s,l)
        case l' of
           LogOK _ _ -> runStateT (k a) (s',l'{stepS=1+stepS l'})
           LogErr _ _-> do return ( a, s',l') -- <- This line is causing trouble

    fail str = StateT $ \ _ -> fail str
```

I tried to modify the behaviour of the `Monad` instance to test the value of the `LogS` data type and according to its value :

- Perform an increment of `stepS` (to count the number of statement) and many other things (not implemented yet) and continue the monad execution.
- Or stop the monad execution and return the actual state.

Do you know what is wrong with my code and how to correct it ?

Comment: You can not return `a`, since it should be a `StateT s m b`, not `StateT s m a`.

Comment: I have understand the mistake but I really don't see how to correct it? Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a page from other monads that signal errors in the middle of a monadic computation.  They don't `return` the error value, because that's not generally possible: a monadic action of type `m b` can *only* `return` a value of type `b`, not some other arbitrary type like `(a,s,LogS)`.  Instead, these other error-signaling monads use a sum type for representing errors.  For example, the monadic action `Either MyNastyError b` can only `return` a value of type `b` (by using `Right`), but it can signal an error of type `MyNastyError` using `Left`.

Also, you won't generally be able to produce an `(a,s,LogS)` because not enough is known about the type `a`.  It's just the return type of some action that was bound into the overall monadic action immediately before the action that ultimately failed, so the caller won't generally be ready to do anything with it.  You can return `(s,LogS)` though, since that type will be fixed across all actions in a given monad.

Specifically, you can redefine your `StateT` type as:

```
newtype StateT s m a
  = StateT { runStateT :: (s, LogS) -> m (Maybe a, s, LogS) }
  deriving (Functor)
```

This uses `Maybe a` to signal failure.  A computation that returns `(Just x, s, l)` can continue, but a `(Nothing, s, l)` is ready to stop and dump its state and log.

With this type, the two `LogS` constructors are now redundant, because failure is already signaled by the `Maybe a` value, so `LogS` can be simplified to:

```
data LogS = LogS { stepS :: Int , logS :: [String] }
  deriving (Show)
```

The appropriate `Applicative` and `Monad` instances can be updated to:

```
instance (Monad m) => Applicative (StateT s m) where
  pure a = StateT $ \(s, l) -> return (Just a, s, l)
  (<*>) = ap
instance (Monad m) => Monad (StateT s m) where
  return = pure
  m >>= k = StateT $ \(s, l) -> do
    (maybeA, s', l') <- runStateT m (s, l)
    case maybeA of
      Nothing -> return (Nothing, s', l')
      Just a -> runStateT (k a) (s', l' {stepS = 1 + stepS l'})
  fail err = StateT $ \(s, l) -> return (Nothing, s, l { logS = err:logS l })
```

Note that I think `fail` makes more sense if it does "nice" failure in this monad instead of using the base monad's `fail`.  I'm assuming here that the `logS` field is in reverse order, so latest messages are appended to the head.

The full code:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

module TestStateJLJ1  where

import Data.Functor.Identity
import Control.Monad

data LogS = LogS { stepS :: Int , logS :: [String] }
  deriving (Show)

initLogS :: LogS
initLogS = LogS 1 []

newtype StateT s m a
  = StateT { runStateT :: (s, LogS) -> m (Maybe a, s, LogS) }
  deriving (Functor)

instance (Monad m) => Applicative (StateT s m) where
  pure a = StateT $ \(s, l) -> return (Just a, s, l)
  (<*>) = ap
instance (Monad m) => Monad (StateT s m) where
  return = pure
  m >>= k = StateT $ \(s, l) -> do
    (maybeA, s', l') <- runStateT m (s, l)
    case maybeA of
      Nothing -> return (Nothing, s', l')
      Just a -> runStateT (k a) (s', l' {stepS = 1 + stepS l'})
  fail err = StateT $ \(s, l) -> return (Nothing, s, l { logS = err:logS l })

type State s = StateT s Identity

state :: (Monad m) => ((s, LogS) -> (Maybe a, s, LogS)) -> StateT s m a
state f = StateT $ return . f
```

Comment: Great and precise answer !